# Why is cheese not allowed on the slow carb diet?

Tags: diet

Most cheese is low in carbohydrates and according to [one site it has almost no glycemic effect](http://getfit.jillianmichaels.com/low-glycemic-foods-cheese-2008.html) (b/c it's so low in carbs)

Lots of [sources](http://www.4hbtalk.com/blog/cheese-slow-carb-diet/) say most Cheese (except for Cottage Cheese and Feta and Parmesan)  is not allowed:

> Cottage cheese has been mentioned by Tim Ferriss, and others, to be OK
>   as a last resort, or backup. This doesn’t mean relying on it every
>   day...
>
> Feta cheese has been argued by some people as being OK,...
>
> Parmesan has been mentioned, in some recipes, .... Other than the 3
>   above, most other **cheese should be avoided**. In general, cheese packs a
>   lot of fat, a small to moderate amount of protein, and the potential
>   to delivery a lot more energy than you’ll notice, making it easier to
>   overeat.

But that rational "too much energy" seems a bit counter to the "slow carb" diet.
So I'm confused.

Comment: Also, is it "Low" or "Slow"?

Comment: I also wondered why it is not allowed. Tim's point is that cheese as well as milk contains lactose. That's true, but cheese contains significantly less lactose than milk, and moreover, some aged cheese does not contain lactose at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for avoiding high glycemic foods, is to avoid the risk of high triglycerides, which tends to result in accumulation of body fat (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11602065). Foods that are high in fat, also lead to an increase in blood triglycerides (http://www.webmd.com/cholesterol-management/lowering-triglyceride-levels). Accordingly, if you're avoiding high glycemic foods, it makes sense to also avoid high fat foods.

Comment: I was going to ask "but why are eggs 'in' " but it looks like (as I've read before) that eggs don't increase tg's  :http://www.livestrong.com/article/464868-eggs-triglycerides/